# YML files in Symfony - can you get associative arrays more than 1 level down?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, yaml

I have a load of data I want to store in `/apps/frontend/modules/builder/config/module.yml`.

I have it looking something like:

```
all:
  series_options:
    compact:
      name: Compact
      description: Something small.
      enabled: 1
    large:
      name: Large
      description: Bit bigger.
      enabled: 0
```

In the actions.class if I write this:

```
sfConfig::get('mod_builder_series_options_compact');
```

I get this

```
Array
(
  [name] => Compact
  [description] => Something small.
  [enabled] => 1
)
```

Perfect. But I want to write this:

```
sfConfig::get('mod_builder_series_options');
```

Which gives `NULL`.

Is there any way I can get this to return the full associative array to its full depth so I can iterate through the different options?

Answer (score 5):

You can add a level with a dot before its name to force array on certain level:

```
all:
  .options:
    series_options:
      compact:
        name: Compact
        description: Something small.
        enabled: 1
      large:
        name: Large
        description: Bit bigger.
        enabled: 0
```

Now you should be able to access your settings with:

```
sfConfig::get('mod_builder_series_options');
```

Remember that module configuration is only accessible in the module it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Typical, as soon as I resort to posting the answer hits me in the face...

```
$series = sfYaml::load('../apps/frontend/modules/builder/config/module.yml');  
print_r($series);die;
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
  [all] => Array
    (
        [series_options] => Array
            (
                [compact] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Compact
                        [description] => Something small.
                        [enabled] => 1
                    )

                [large] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Large
                        [description] => Bit bigger.
                        [enabled] => 0
                    )
            )

    )

)
```

Guessing that sfConfig wasnt really meant for this purpose, where sfYaml certainly looks like it was!

Hope this helps someone else!